# Problemas para crear y correr un proyecto en Java (Build error / Launch error)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-16

recién estoy empezando en Java y estoy teniendo algunos problemas con Eclipse. Estoy siguiendo tal cual el siguiente video [min 16:22](https://youtu.be/Lj97ujkeUXc?t=982) En ese minuto en donde él crea su proyecto yo lo hago igual, es ahí donde me sale esto al crearlo (aún no se llegó a escribir código ni nada):

```
'Building' has encountered a problem.

Errors occurred during the build.

Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ini'.
For input string: "G" under radix 16
```

Y después si omito esa advertencia/error y quiero correr el código (un "hola mundo") Me sale "Launch error" (Sin decir error de qué) (Supongo que se debe al build error anterior)
Código:

```
public class Primera {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        System.out.print("Hola mundo");
    }
}
```

Para correrlo estoy con una consola y dándole al boton de correr el código, nada raro
Estoy haciendo todo tal cual el video, no sé qué pasa. Al que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

### Versiones

La versión de eclipse: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

De jdk me sale esto cuando pongo en la terminal

```
java -version
```

> java 16.0.2 2021-07-20 |
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67) |
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)

```
javac -version
```

> javac 16.0.2

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No tenes que incluir imagenes, si no el codigo que te genera problemas....

Comment: Buenas, Eliana, bienvenida al sitio. Parece que hay un bug de Eclipse relacionado con el mensaje de error que mencionas. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564922 En el video ese parecen estar usando la version 1.7 de Java, no la 16. ¿Sabes cuál tienes tú? Para prácticas sencillas intenta bajarte un jdk 1.8 y en el paso indicado en el minuto ese, selecciona esa versión en lugar de la 16.

Comment: @RubioRic Muchas gracias!! Ya no tengo error al crear el proyecto, pero al querer correr el código sigo con un Launch error
¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: No sé como lo estás intentando correr. Si te pones en el Package Explorer sobre la clase, pulsas con el botón derecho y en el menú emergente seleccionas primero Run As y luego Java Aplication, no deberías tener problemas. En la consola te debería salir "Hola Mundo"

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129375/discussion-on-question-by-eliana-h-problemas-para-crear-y-correr-un-proyecto-en).

Comment: Podrías instalar el package de Eclipse IDE for Java Developers y no deberías de tener problema. El enlace: [Eclipse Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXbxI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXbxI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación si vas a usar jdk-16.0.2 es que también tengas la última versión de Eclipse que actualmente es la 2021-06, es la que yo tengo ahora mismo.

Puedes descargar desde este link: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2021-06/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe o también puedes actualizar desde el mismo eclipse si vas al menú superior y pulsas en “Help” y después en “Check for updates” aunque esta forma normalmente tarda bastante.

Dicho esto te recomiendo tener varias versiones de Java instaladas en tu ordenador, yo concretamente tengo ahora mismo lo siguiente debido a varias pruebas que hago normalmente -> jre7 que aunque es antiguo me sirve para usar iReport para informes, jre1.8.0, jdk1.8.0, jdk-11.0.11 y jdk-16.0.2, de esta forma desde eclipse puedo seleccionar en cualquier momento la librería que yo quiera dependiendo de lo que este haciendo en ese momento ya que hay algunas incompatibilidades entre versiones, que con el tiempo iras conociendo.

Te paso este link de archivo donde tienes varias versiones de jdk, de esta forma lo tendrás siempre a mano -> https://jdk.java.net/archive/

No obstante, en la ruta donde se aloja eclipse -> C:\Users\Robert\eclipse\jee-2021-06\eclipse, se encuentra el archivo eclipse.ini y que comparto el mío contigo por si quieres compararle con el tuyo:

```html
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.11/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Robert\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.200.v20210429-1609
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\Robert\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.20.0.20210612-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--illegal-access=permit
```